# ios8 gesture recognizer does not work on WKWebView with swift

Tags: swift, ios8, uigesturerecognizer, wkwebview

i"m trying to implement a long press gesture recognizer on a WKWebView as follows:

```
var webView: WKWebView?
let longPressRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer()

override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()

    var webViewConfig: WKWebViewConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    webViewConfig.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
    webViewConfig.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false

    self.webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame, configuration: webViewConfig)
    self.view = self.webView!

    //hook the long press event
    longPressRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: "onLongPress:")
    self.webView!.scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer)
}    

func onLongPress(gestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer){
    NSLog("long press detected")

}
```

i don't get an error but i cant seem to make it trigger the onLongPress function.

Comment: try this: https://github.com/theniceboy/HoldToSaveImage

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You didn't set the `delegate` of the gesture recognizer.

```
//hook the long press event
longPressRecognizer.delegate = self
longPressRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: "onLongPress:")
self.webView!.scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer)
```

In case that it still doesn't work, this may probably due to `WKWebView` already has its own gesture recognizers. Then add the following method to your class:

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

And in your event method check for the gesture began:

```
func onLongPress(gestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer){
    if gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {
        NSLog("long press detected")
    }
}
```

Comment: it works! but now the event is fired continuously instead of once, what would be the proper way of dealing with it?